# Exporting ServiceHost configuration

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I created a ServiceHost, and I want to see its configuration file so I can generate the same service's configurations within the `.config` file of another service.

This is the code:

```
    using (ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(RemoteDeploy.Deploy), new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:61115/Service/{1}/", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(), "Deploy"))))
    {
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(RemoteDeploy.IDeploy), new BasicHttpBinding(), string.Empty);
        ServiceDiscoveryBehavior discoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
        serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior());
        discoveryBehavior.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
        serviceHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to export the configuration to XML or any other file, or to get the path where the configurations are deployed?

Comment: Might be mistaken, but I thought config files replaced code and vice-versa. Are you sure a .config is generated?

Comment: that is just what i'm asking. because i want to know how to generate the same behavior for my other web service when i deploy it to IIS and not with C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're out of luck on this one. I don't know of any way to get the ServiceHost to generate its configuration as a file.

Consider configuring your ServiceHost via a configuration file and simply sharing it between your hosting environments that way.

Comment: my problem is that i can't seem to get the same defenitions. my original problem was this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144975/wcf-discovery-problem-with-finding-a-service